# how do I keep track of a minimum across recursion calls

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying my way around practising recursion and I want to find the minimum ways to generate a sum with given coins.

I did figure out a way to do using a global variable but I've heard it's not really optimal to do it this way

This is my code

```
minres = 10000
def count(sum, i, coins, temp, res):
    global minres
    if sum == 0:
        minres = min(minres, res)
        return

    if sum < 0:
        return

    if i == len(coins):
        return

    temp.append(coins[i])
    count(sum-coins[i], i, coins, temp, res+1)
    temp.pop()
    count(sum, i+1, coins, temp, res)

    return minres


coins = [9, 6, 5, 1]
print(count(11, 0, coins, [], 0))
```

This code works and I get the answer 2, but is there a way I can do it without a global variable or something of the sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your function that doesn't rely on a `global` definition of `minres`. By passing `minres` to and returning it from every function call, it no longer needs to be "remembered" outside the scope of each function call:

```
def count(sm, i, coins, res, temp=None, minres = 10000):
    if temp is None:
        temp = []
    if sm == 0:
        minres = min(minres, res)

    if sm < 0:
        return minres

    if i == len(coins):
        return minres

    temp.append(coins[i])
    minres = count(sm-coins[i], i, coins, res+1, temp, minres)
    temp.pop()
    minres = count(sm, i+1, coins, res, temp, minres)

    return minres
```

A couple of other changes I've made:

1. `temp = []` in your call signature [is dicey](https://florimond.dev/en/posts/2018/08/python-mutable-defaults-are-the-source-of-all-evil/#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20when%20passing%20a,or%20even%20a%20class%20instance.) because the default argument is mutable. Better to use `None` as a cue within your call to default `temp` to `[]`.
2. I've avoided using `sum` as a variable name given it is a builtin function within Python. By reassigning something to the name `sum` other than its original meaning, you risk confusing things later on.